# Using cherrypy in two modules but with only one cherrypy instance

Tags: python, module, cherrypy

I am using cherrypy for a project and use it in a main python script main.py
In a method within the main app I import a module called authentication

`from authentication import auth` and then pass it the variable args. cherrypy has been used here already obviously

```
@cherrypy.expose
def auth(self, *args):
    from authentication import auth
    auth = auth()

    page = common.header('Log in')

    authString = auth.login(*args)

    if authString:
        page += common.barMsg('Logged in succesfully', 1)
        page += authString
    else:
        page += common.barMsg('Authentication failed', 0)

    page += common.footer()

    return page
```

From within authentication.py I want to set session variables so I included cherrypy again

```
def login(self, *args):
    output = "<b>&quot;args&quot; has %d variables</b><br/>\n" % len(args)

    if cherrypy.request.body_params is None:
        output += """<form action="/auth/login" method="post" name="login">
            <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="username"/>
            <input type="password" maxlength="255" name="password"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In"></input>
        </form>"""
        output += common.barMsg('Not a member yet? Join me <a href="/auth/join">here</a>', 8)

    return output
```

The problem is the error `HTTPError: (400, 'Unexpected body parameters: username, password')` when I use this. I want to have the cherrypy instance from main.py accesible in authentication.py to set session variables here. How can I do that?

I have also tried passing the cherrypy object like so `authString = auth.login(cherrypy, *args)` and omitted its inclusion in authentication.py however get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to answer this so quickly but a little research turns out that the argument **kwargs ommitted from the method auth causes body_parameters to be rejected by cherrypy as it wasn't expecting them. To fix this:

```
main.py

@cherrypy.expose
def auth(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from authentication import auth
    auth = auth()

    page = common.header('Log in')

    authString = auth.login(cherrypy, args)

    if authString:
        page += common.barMsg('Logged in succesfully', 1)
        page += authString
    else:
        page += common.barMsg('Authentication failed', 0)

    page += common.footer()

    return page

authentication.py

def login(self, cherrypy, args):
    output = "<b>&quot;args&quot; has %d variables</b><br/>\n" % len(args)

    if cherrypy.request.body_params is None:
        output += """<form action="/auth/login" method="post" name="login">
            <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="username"/>
            <input type="password" maxlength="255" name="password"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In"></input>
        </form>"""
        output += common.barMsg('Not a member yet? Join me <a         href="/auth/join">here</a>', 8)

    return output
```